# SKPhysicsJointSpring between 2 objects that are not direct children of the scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I wanted to mix 2 tutorials, namely:

http://hub.ae/blog/2014/03/26/soft-body-physics-jellyusing-spritekit/

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html
(Example: Centering the Scene on a Node part)

I got both working one by one, but I've a bug when I mix both.

If my code starts like this:

```
[self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
_myWorld = [SKNode node];
[self addChild:_myWorld]; 
[self createPlayer]; // I replaced all [self addchild's to [_myWorld addChild]
```

then camera follows the player but there are no joints created!

If I put `[self createPlayer]` to the top and leave all `[self addchilds]` as they are (because _myWorld isn't created yet) then there are joints which are working perfectly but camera doesn't follow player, since player isn't in _myWorld.

I leave `[self.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];` as it is all the time.

Any idea where I go wrong?

Comment: You can't expect people to spend time reading tutorial links and figure out what is wrong/missing. Post the minimal amount of code needed to convey your issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I moved the parts into _myWorld as told in the Apple guide, I didn't know I also had to shift anchor points, as they are always in scene coordinates.

Adding these lines solved the problem:

```
CGPoint p1 = [self.scene convertPoint:CGPointMake(point1.position.x+self.frame.size.width/2, point1.position.y+self.frame.size.height/2) fromNode:_myWorld];
CGPoint p2 = [self.scene convertPoint:CGPointMake(point2.position.x+self.frame.size.width/2, point2.position.y+self.frame.size.height/2) fromNode:_myWorld];
```

in the `AttachPoint` function.